# XML or JAVA code for switching elements in ANDROID

Tags: java, android, xml

Very new to programming here. I am trying to program an activity for Android in .xml and .java and I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to switch one element for another by pressing a button.

The screen I am working on will have an option to search through a list of items and the option to add items to this list. I would like the search bar and any adding options to be hidden by default, with the option to show either of them by pressing the according button. Press the search options button and the search bar should appear, press the adding options button and the search bar should be hidden and in its place should show adding options instead.

Is this possible in .xml or .java and if so what kind of elements or methods should I be looking into to achieve this? Below you will find the code that I have so far in .xml, where the editText1 should be the search bar and which should be replaced with adding options if imageButton2 is pressed.

Many thanks in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bgmenu"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:src="@drawable/bproductsbanner"
        android:paddingStart="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/ibProductsBanner"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bgminibutton" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:src="@drawable/bssearch" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:src="@drawable/bsadd" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Search.." />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Product List"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp" 
        android:gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the visibility as gone in your xml to your search bar:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Search.." 
    android:visibility="gone"/>
```

And then you have to change visibility when you click the button:

```
ImageButton ib = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
final EditText search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

ib.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        search.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});
```

P.s. I'm supposing that your search bar is the `EditText` with id `editText1` and your option button is the `ImageButton` with id `imageButton1`

Comment: Correct! Seems like the setVisibility line was what I was looking for. Many thanks!

Comment: @LarsScholing If it solved your problem, accept or upvote one of our two answers!

Comment: Tried doing so, but it seems like I need a minimum reputation of 15 to upvote. Only have 1 reputation currently as I only just signed up for Stackoverflow

Edit: ah accepting the answer seemed to work ;)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have defined the search bar in your xml as an EditText

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/search" ...
```

Then in your activity (java) you get a reference to it by doing

```
View search = findViewById(R.id.search);
```

and then when clicking the respective button you can play with the visibility attribute

```
search.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // View.GONE
```

Comment: That sounds like it should work. Ill try to implement the visibility line in my java code and it seems like it should be possible to put elements on top of eachother in a RelativeLayout. Thanks a lot!